# monitor the network

Tags: networking

i live in a flat with other guys and we have a problem with internet connection (we have a flat contract). after a while we understand that there is a computer that (probabilly due to some windows vista virus) if it is connected to our router, cause the network to be super slow and crash.

i'd like to find out a way to monitor all package in our wireless network and understand how many packages and what kind of packs it send for flooding our connection.

in our flat we have windows, mac and ubuntu. some advice?
(i am on ubuntu and so i'd prefer something on linux side)

Comment: [wireshark?](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) it's available for Windows and Unix. For Ubuntu look [here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Wireshark). For a wireless network its a [little tricky](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) so you could take a look if your rooter offers capturing like for [example fritzbox products](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/8541/how-can-i-capture-traffic-with-a-fritz-box).

Answer (score 1):

- Do you have access to the various computers:

If so, start with the basics, run one of the many online virus scanners and malware detection tools. If the problem continues, you can install a bandwidth monitor like NetLimiter Lite.

- If you dont, or you want a more permanent solution:

Handle the problem at your router, does your router webpage have an option to turn on Quality of Service ( QOS )? Most slow downs happen because upload bandwidth is being maxed.

If your router doesn't, see if your router supports replacment firwmare: DD-WRT, Tomato, or Gargoyle, where the former has a wider hardware support, the latter two have per client bandwidth usage stats.

Problems may not be actually a pure bandwidth issue, things like torrents or rogue programs can open so many connections that low spec routers simply can't handle them, even if very little bandwidth is being transferred.